# Reporting the coordinate of a left clicked (and held) mouse in SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Firstly I don't even know if what I'm trying to do is even possible so please forgive me on that front.

I have created a program that allows graphics to be displayed in SVG. As part of this I want the user to be able to sketch notes with their mouse.

Is there a way to capture a mouse coordinates using javascript (or jQuery) if the left mouse button is pressed and held? What I'm struggling to get my head around is how to capture the series of positions to generate a path. As far as I understand I would need to grab a coordinate at a set timestep if the position has changed (psudo code below).

```
if (leftClicked)
{
   var positionArray[];
   var MC = getMouseCoordinates();
   positionArray[0] = MC;
   var i = 1;
   while(leftClicked)
   {
      if getMouseCoordinates() != MC
      {
         MC = getMouseCoordinates();
         positionArray[i] = MC;
      }
      i++;
   }
}
```

But despite a few hours reading I can't find a way to implement this in JavaScript.

Also my SVG is embedded in a HTML page. I don't know how to localise the coordinate reporting just to that SVG and not the entire page?

Sorry, I know this is quite a vague question but I don't even know where to start with this one...

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the other way round, rather than look for a button press and then try to track the mouse, track the mouse and check if the mouse moves whether the button is pressed.
I.e. attach a [mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/mousemove) event handler and check for button = 0

This [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/svg/swarm-of-motes.xhtml) tracks mousemove events, although it doesn't check for buttons being pressed, you'll have to add that yourself using the information [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/mousemove)